# MySQL - UPDATE Tables based on date/time

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a table named USER, with the columns: ID, Name, Password, Birthday, LastLogin, etc...

How do I update all inactive users?

Ex: I want to change pass of all users that logged in for the last time at 2010-01-01 or before.

UPDATE SQL:

```
update USER set Password=MD5('new_pass');
```

But how to make it attend to the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update USER set Password=MD5('new_pass') where LastLogin < your-date
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE USER
SET Password = MD5('new_pass')
WHERE LastLogin <= '2010-01-01'
```